# Asp.net Web API With No Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net

We want to start using Asp.net web api for our future enterprise services however we do not want to use EF for data access.

Are there any samples out there for Asp.net Web APi working with regular ado.net classes instead of EF?

Thanks.

Comment: EF is a data access technology, specifically an Object Relational Mapper (or ORM). There are others like it (NHibernate, PetaPoco, LLBLGEN, etc.) as well as ADO.NET, etc.. Why are you choosing to stay away from EF?

Comment: What are you having trouble with that you need a sample for?

Comment: Web API is totally independent from data access layer. You probably saw a couple of WEB API samples that happened to work with EF. Just look for ADO.NET examples without WEB API and then think about connect them into WEB API. I believe, however, there would be nobody who tries to work  with non-ORM framework like ADO.NET for ASP.NET MVC unless there is a pretty good reason that I can't anticipate. It's like having manual windows in BMW.

Comment: +1. The issue is that the Visual Studio 2012 template pulls down EF with NuGet, along with some other (EF-dependent) packages that are *not* needed by all projects.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349255/basic-project-template-for-asp-net-web-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for [code samples for how to use e.g., SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlDataReader?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090.aspx)

You would use the classes in System.Data.SqlClient if you are trying to talk to SQL Server,  System.Data.OracleClient if you're trying to talk to Oracle, or System.Data.Odbc if you're trying to talk to MySQL.

Here are [some code samples for how to call a stored procedure from ADO.NET.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  Good luck!