# Basic Project Template for Asp.net Web Api?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am wondering if there is a "basic" asp.net web api template. I only see one "web api" project and it brings out of bit of stuff in and not sure if all of it I need.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can either:

1) Create a new *MVC4 project > choose Web API template* - but that, as you point out, brings in a lot of stuff, including Modernizer, jQuery, Knockout and so on

2) Create a new *ASP.NET empty Web application* and install Web API web host from Nuget:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi
```

You then end up with a very clean, basic project, including only the necessary DLLs.

3) If you want to self host Web API (not do an ASP.NET MVC4 project), you can create a *new console application* and install Web API self host from Nuget:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.SelfHost
```

which is perfect for lightweight services, but obviously you don't host inside IIS anymore so there are additional release/deployment considerations. You can read more about self host here -> http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/self-host-a-web-api

Comment: As of Visual Studio 2013 (maybe sooner?) you can select the **Empty** template as suggested in Option 2) and then check the **Web API** checkbox under the _Add folders and core references for_.

Answer (score 5):

For **Mvc 5** in **VS 2015**, I select **empty project** template and **check WebApi** section. It give me clean project with just WebApi references installed.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion goes for [Empty ASP.NET Web API Project Template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a989a149-4bc3-4292-ac8a-5101ee1722d7), which is a VS extension.

There is a pretty good demonstration of it in [this Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/615805/Creating-a-Clean-Minimal-Footprint-ASP-NET-WebAPI).

I use it without any sort of problems and it really is lighter than default WebAPI template.

Comment: Looks like a great template, but no 2013 version.